# Get stored procedure definition from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

One of our dev database got overwritten and couple of stored procedure got missing from it. We don't have any definition of that stored procedure in prod and test. We are planning to restore previous backups and see if we can get the definition for there but before we do that I want to know if there is a way we can get the definition from Entity Framework or from .net code somewhere?

Comment: No. That is like asking if you can your c# code from the database. Stored procedure code is in the database. If you lost it you will have to restore from a backup. Then I would suggest you implement version control for your databases.

Comment: Stored procedure statements are **code** - and you should **REALLY** put **ALL** code in source control. Take this as a lesson and do this from now on! No excuses....

Comment: Thanks guys.I thought it was impossible but asked anyways if there is any chance. This will help me convince my manager to start using Version Control on DB too, already on VC on all the project solutions.